# What is it? Simple but fun riddle

Tags: riddle

> The one who makes it, sells it.
>   The one who buys it, never uses it.
>   The one that uses it, never knows he's using it.

<sub>Source: An anonymous guy I met online.</sub>

Knowing all of you guys, you will solve it in a minute or less. I thought it was a fun riddle though.

Comment: I remember this Chestnut

Comment: I've seen this at least 2 times in here.

Comment: @dcfyj marius I'm sorry guys.

Comment: Yeah, And it is a simple idea which anyone can think of.

Comment: @TristandeJager Ts'all good, it happens.

Comment: This riddle always reminds me of my job...  The one who makes it, has to maintain it. The one who maintains it, isn't allowed to touch it. The one who's allowed to touch it, doesn't know anything about it. The one who buys it, never uses it, but every now and then brings it back up again... in my case it's an application. IT is the worst.

Comment: @user1566694 Hahaha, same here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is

> A coffin. Self explanatory.

The one who makes it, sells it.
The one who buys it, never uses it.
The one that uses it, never knows he's using it.

> The one who uses it is already dead. He can never know.

Comment: You got it! I will mark this solved in 10 minutes.

Comment: Well, there probably exist some people that are dying that like to buy their own coffin

Comment: @IvoBeckers There are always special snowflakes

Answer (score 4):

Already answered but one more -

> A non smoking guy gets a ciggerate from a ciggerate seller and adds marijuana to it. The one who smokes it doesn't know he is high. :D

Comment: Haha! Creative. I love it